# How to make watermark with FFmpeg

Tags: 7, files

I am using FFmpeg 0.10.7 on the server and video module (drupal.org/project/video) 7.x-2.10. I'm aware about video watermarking but only when u're using Zencoder. How can i set up a watermark with FFmpeg?

Comment: You may take a look here: https://drupal.org/node/1999000 where a patch is provided by a user for Video module.

Comment: Are you on Windows? I'm experiencing some issues with the paths on Windows. I hope I can fix the bug and submit the patch soon.

Comment: Hello, no i'm on CentOS 6. Have you tried the patch that you have linked before? Did it worked for you?

Comment: I've tried it and got error. Looking at logs, I realized there is a issue with the path to the watermark file (I am on Windows). The last lines of the FFMPEG output had these errors: `Failed to avformat_open_input` and `Error initializing filter 'movie' with args`. This is unlikely that you have any problem with the path (as you are on Linux), but taking a look at the log `/admin/reports/dblog` would possibly help you to find the culprit. Hope this could help you. Let me know if there is an issue.